# Regarding the installation of RVM on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: rvm

I installed RVM using the command `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` and I got all listed Rubies successfully. When I am trying to install `readline` package using the command `rvm package install readline` I am getting the following status:
TEST:software sailakshmi$ `rvm pkg install readline`

```
Beware, 'rvm pkg ...' is deprecated, read about the new autolibs feature: 'rvm help autolibs'.

Checking requirements for osx.
Installing macports
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
sailakshmi password required for 'make install':
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system...................................................
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkgconfig, libiconv, libyaml, libffi, readline, libksba, openssl, curl-ca-bundle, sqlite3, zlib, gdbm, ncurses
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Certificates in '/opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Fetching readline-5.2.tar.gz to /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1989k  100 1989k    0     0   107k      0  0:00:18  0:00:18 --:--:--  119k
Extracting readline to /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/src/readline-5.2
Applying patch '/Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/patches/readline-5.2/shobj-conf.patch'....
Prepare readline in /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/src/readline-5.2 .............................
Error running '__rvm_autoreconf -is --force',
please read /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/log/1384489495/readline_autoreconf.log
Configuring readline in /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/src/readline-5.2
.......................................................................................................................................................................
Compiling readline in /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/src/readline-5.2
...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Installing readline to /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/usr .............................................................................

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Fetching readline-6.2.tar.gz to /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2224k  100 2224k    0     0   188k      0  0:00:11  0:00:11 --:--:--  334k
Extracting readline to /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/src/readline-6.2
Applying patch '/Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/patches/readline-6.2/patch-shobj-conf.diff'....
Prepare readline in /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/src/readline-6.2
...............................
Error running '__rvm_autoreconf -is --force',
please read /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/log/1384489495/readline_autoreconf.log
Configuring readline in /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/src/readline-6.2
................................................................................................................................
Compiling readline in /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/src/readline-6.2
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Installing readline to /Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/usr ..................................................................

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force
```

please help me out here `Error running '__rvm_autoreconf -is --force'`

Answer (score 0):

1. you do not need to install the rvm readline package, new rvm detects your package manager and installs readline for you before installing ruby so ruby should be working fine with readling - if it does not open a bug report here => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues
2. if you want to pursue the problem with readline compilation please also open a bug including `/Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/log/1384489495/readline_autoreconf.log` and `/Users/sailakshmi/.rvm/log/1384489495/readline_autoreconf.log` - but those did not break anything installation continued without any other problems.